# "The type Main must implement the inherited abstract method TextWatcher.beforeTextChanged(charSequence,int,int,int)

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a TextWatcher editbox.afterTextChanged listenering to my "Main" activity where I have already used an onFocusListener. I receive this error message on the line where I declare the Main class:

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener, TextWatcher{
```

the listener is set to an edittext box with:

```
etBox1.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

and the code to implement with the catch is:

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
   {    doMyCalcs(); }

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You implement all three methods in [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { ... }
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { ... }
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { ... }
```

You only implemented the first one.

Comment: What if I only need the afterTextChanged()? How do I fake the other two, with a method that does nothing?

Comment: Just copy and paste the lines above for the other two methods, removing the '...' from between the curly braces.

Comment: Its works! Thanks. But I have no idea why I have to implement listeners that I will never use. Looks like a waste of code.

Comment: Yep. The alternative is for the framework to define an interface for each of the methods. I guess they figure that most people will want to implement all three or none at all.