# Typing to two edittext fields at same time

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

How can I type into two edittext boxes using softkeyboard popup on android.

If I type for example the word 'cat' in one box then it shows in the other.

If this cannot be done then is there a way to show every letter typed into the box somewhere else on the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) like this for your one EditText

```
firstedittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            secondedittext.setText(firstedittext.getText() + "");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {                
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

hope help

**EDIT**

add these lines in your activity where you have your other imports

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
```

Comment: Thanks but i am getting errors on textwatcher "the type new textwatcher(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Textwatcher.afterTextchanged(Editable)" and "Editable cannot be resolved to type"

please help me

Comment: Thanks Deepak one other problem i'm having though i have the edit text one at the bottom and the primary one i'm typing to at the top, the problem is i have a scrollview xml and when i type it auto scrolls from the bottom of the screen to the top and i don't want this to do this, i've tried removing focus from the top but this means i can't type to that box, removing focus does prevent the autoscroll, do you know who i can stop autoscroll from occuring in the code you have given me?

Comment: Add this attribute in your manifest.xml to your Activity
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" hope help

Comment: unfortunatley adjustpan stops all scrollview from scrolling :(

Answer (score 2):

Implement `TextWatcher` for your `EditTexts`. And now inside it, get the Editable and set it to the Other `EditText`.

```
  EditText edit1=new EditText(this);
    EditText edit2=new EditText(this);

    edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            edit2.setText(s);

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: here the each time new character will replace the previous one.just check it

Comment: when the user time new character, it will just replace the old one

Comment: Thanks but i am getting errors on textwatcher "the type new textwatcher(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Textwatcher.afterTextchanged(Editable)" and "Editable cannot be resolved to type"

please help me

Answer (score 1):

use [textwatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for edit text. here you can implement as when you are entering data in one edittext then other edit text also filled with the characters you are entering

```
 EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit01);
 EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit02);     
 et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        et2.setText(et1.getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {                
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but i am getting errors on textwatcher "the type new textwatcher(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Textwatcher.afterTextchanged(Editable)" and "Editable cannot be resolved to type"

please help me

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225731/the-type-main-must-implement-the-inherited-abstract-method-textwatcher-beforete)

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextWatcher` on one EditText and inside it use `EditText2.setText()`

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) which changes text of an `EditView` or `TextView` inside its [`onTextChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method.  Set this watcher on the source view using [`addTextChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

This is my logic:

first add text watcher on your first Edittext where in you will typein

```
OnCreate
et1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
et2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
et1.addTextChangedListener(addTextWatcher);
//now you need to add this


TextWatcher addTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() { 
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {   

    }  
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {  
        NewString= et1.getText().length();
    et2.settext(NewString);

   }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

    }
        };

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {   
    }
```